# Deactive ProcessBuilder with Metadata

Tags: process-builder, metadata-api

This is the top of my process builder metadata file. I read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) and [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DhHjAAK) that you can set the status to 'Draft' and it will appear as inactive on the UI. Then I read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm) that you have to set 'activeVersionNumber' to 0 and that 'FlowDefinition' element will override 'Flow' element's status field. But our process builder.flow file does not have a 'FlowDefinition' element. So what do I do ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<status>Draft</status>
```

... Also we don't have any FlowDefinition files. Why would that be?

Found FlowDefinition file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the `.flow` file inside `flows` folder. There will be another file with extension `.flowDefinition` inside `flowDefinitions` folder.

The `.flowDefinition` file has details about which version is active for a given flow.

**EDIT:**

Force IDE or Force migration tool will retrieve `flowDefinition` files only if `package.xml` contains the below elements:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>FlowDefinition</name>
</types>
```

**EDIT 2:**

- `flowDefinition` files are deprecated in v44.0 and above.
- Before v44.0, active flow version number is stored in `flowDefinition` files and with v44.0, we can control active version inside the `.flow` file itself.
- To get the `status` tag in `.flow` files make sure to use version number 44.0 or greater in `package.xml` file. I tried this in my developer edition org and it worked.

> As part of this upgrade, flow definitions are no longer necessary when
>   you deploy or retrieve via Metadata API. If you deploy with flow
>   definitions, the active version numbers in the flow definitions
>   override the status fields in the flows. For example, the active
>   version number in the flow definition is version 3, and the latest
>   version of the flow is version 4 with the status field as Active.
>   After you deploy your flow, the active version is version 3.

Comment: We really don't have that folder in source. Nor is there one in the metadata available  in the app connected with force.com IDE.

Comment: @SallyRothroat check the updated answer

Comment: I'm still confused, I now have a FlowDefinition file(see its contents in the edit) there is nothing here that would prevent the <status> field mentioned above from deactivating the PB.

Comment: And FlowDefinitions are deprecated in v44 so where does that leave us ?

Comment: @SallyRothroat let me know if you still have questions.